# Firefox is crashing and I am getting ConnectionResetError when used Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I started working on a python script that is going to navigate through a webpage and going to take some necessary datas for me.

I found a code that uses selenium in it to navigate the internet.

The problem is, when I run the code, Firefox is crashing and I am getting the **ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host** error.

I couldn't find the glitch and need a help.

Here is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# initiate
driver = webdriver.Firefox() # initiate a driver, in this case Firefox
driver.get("URL_HERE") # go to the url

# log in
username_field = driver.find_element_by_name(Username_here) # get the username field
password_field = driver.find_element_by_name(Password_here) # get the password field
username_field.send_keys("...") # enter in your username
password_field.send_keys("...") # enter in your password
password_field.submit() # submit it

# print HTML
html = driver.page_source
print (html)
```

Comment: Try downgrading your Firefox to an older version

Comment: Are there any specific version that is causing this problem?

Comment: May be you [can check this](http://www.seleniumtests.com/2016/07/marionette-web-driver-and-stf.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants to have an answer, 47 versioned Firefox browsers have a problem with this. So I've tried to owrk with a lower version then 47 and it worked.

I'd suggest if it is not necessary, use Chrome. (First you need to download the driver) That way you are not going to stuck with something like this.